# HttpMessageNotWritableException when returning a Mono for Content-Type 'multipart/form-data in Webflux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, multipartform-data, spring-webflux

I am trying to return a Mono in an API which is used to upload a file.

This is the signature of the method.

```
@PatchMapping(value = {"/uploadDoc},
              consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}
              produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE,
                      MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
Mono<MyObject> uploadDocument(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestPart("file") FilePart filePart);
```

When I return `Mono<Void>` or `Mono<String>` it works fine. But, when I return a stream of my custom object `Mono<MyObject>`, I'm getting the below error.

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No Encoder for [com.MyObject] with preset Content-Type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------127221087502764453476151'
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageWriterResultHandler.writeBody(AbstractMessageWriterResultHandler.java:172)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
```

The rest of the stack trace.

```
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageWriterResultHandler.writeBody(AbstractMessageWriterResultHandler.java:172)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageWriterResultHandler.writeBody(AbstractMessageWriterResultHandler.java:107)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ResponseBodyResultHandler.handleResult(ResponseBodyResultHandler.java:86)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handleResult(DispatcherHandler.java:169)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.lambda$handle$2(DispatcherHandler.java:147)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1637)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:203)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:203)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1637)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenAcceptInner.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:296)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1637)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1637)
```

**Am I missing something here? Why can't I return an object while uploading a FilePart?**

Comment: Any suggestions on how to solve this problem

Comment: I couldn't find a workaround, so no.